# Looking for bestiary entry for animated training dummy

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

The party is APL 1. I want them to fight a large group of animated training dummies. I want them to have similar stats to goblins, CR 1/3.

Is there something that already exists that matches this neat picture I found, or should I just lay the the goblin stats on the animated training dummy chassis?

[image: reference pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Tiny" Animated Objects are CR 1/2

The statblock, made [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/animated-object/animated-object-tiny), is designed using the rules from [Animated Object (CR3)](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Animated%20Object). Small-Medium Training Dummies with Tiny Animated heads might be enough justification (or say the magic animating them is weak, that's just the way these are, or whatever you want for your justification)

> **Tiny Animated Object CR 1/2**
> XP 200
> N Tiny construct
> Init +2 Senses darkvision 60, low-light vision; Perception -5
> **DEFENSE**
> AC 18, touch 14, flat-footed 16 (+2 Dex, +4 natural, +2 size)
> hp 5 (1d10)
> Fort +0, Ref +2, Will -5
> *Defensive Abilities* hardness 5 Immune Construct Traits
> **OFFENSE**
> Speed 15 ft.
> Melee slam +1 (1d2-2)
> **STATISTICS**
> Str 6, Dex 14, Con -, Int -, Wis 1, Cha 1
> Base Atk +1 CMB +1 CMD 9
> SQ 1 construction point
> **SPECIAL ABILITIES**
> Construction Points
> Tiny animated objects have 1 construction point.

Comment: Don't forget to spend its Construction Point. I recommend **Faster (Ex, 1 CP)**: (One of the object’s movement modes increases by +10 ft.) because 15 speed is pretty bad